# Does the converse of the statement hold?

Tags: general-topology, product-space

I've proved the following statement: "Given $(Z, T_Z)$ the product topological space of $(X, T_X)$ and $(Y, T_Y)$. If $A \in T_X$ and $B \in T_Y$ then $A \times B \in T_Z$".

Converse statement: "Given $(Z, T_Z)$ the product topological space of $(X, T_X)$ and $(Y, T_Y)$. If  $A \times B \in T_Z$ then $A \in T_X$ and $B \in T_Y$".

Now, I'm trying to prove the converse of the statement is not always true but I cannot take find an example to show it's false.

Is the converse of the statement true? If not, please find an example to show it's false.

P/S: I'm thinking the statement is not true because of the union operation of cartesian.

Comment: "Is every open set in the plane an open rectangle?" is probably what you are asking here.

Comment: Dear @MichalAdamaszek, excuse me but I don't quite understand the open rectangle you mentioned

Comment: Then please formulate exactly and precisely the converse you want to disprove and then we will have some starting point to discuss.

Comment: Have just found some typos and editted it.

Comment: If this is really the converse you are interested in then it is true and my first comment was indeed irrelevant. I thought you meant something else as the converse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is empty and $B$ is not open it follows that $A\times B$ is open in the product space. So the converse is false. But if $A$ and $B$ are nonempty and $A \times B$ is open then $A$ and $B$ are open. Proof: Define $f: X \to Z$ by $f(x)=(x,b)$ where $b$ is  fixed element of $B$. Show that this map is continuous. The inverse image under this map of $A\times B$ is exactly $A$ so $A$ is open. Similarly, $B$ is also open.